# PyQt5 web browser with QWebEngineView crashing

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a simple web browser on my application. It works fine, a bit slow, but works fine for some pages. The problem is when i try to load heavier pages like youtube. It crashes and prints `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Here is a simple code of what i'm trying to do:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://youtube.com"))
web.showMaximized()
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is your development environment: Python version, PyQt5 version, PyQtWebEngine version, OS, IDE, etc?

Comment: Python 3.7.3; PyQt5 5.13.0; PyQtWebEngine 5.13.1; OS Windows 10 Pro

Comment: upgrade `PyQt5 5.13.0` to `PyQt5 5.13.1`. What is your IDE?

Comment: I've uprgraded PyQt5 and it solved the problem, but now i'm getting a message on my IDE saying PyQt5-stubs and tools are incompatible with my PyQt5 version. And i can not upgrade this two. I'm working with Pycharm 2019.1.2

Comment: Then downgrade PyQtWebEngine to 5.13

Comment: Everything working now. Thanks